# How do i get rid of an extra row created by Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I have two DataGrids in my WPF .net Application. One of them is working fine, the other one is creating one (empty) row I have no idea where it's added. The datagrids look very similar to me.

Here is how the grids are generated:

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
      Name="grid1">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=HUHU}" MinWidth="120" Header="HUHU" />
            ... some columns
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      Name="grid2" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=HU}" MinWidth="50" Header="HU" />
            ... some columns
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is how the grids are filled:

```
    Dim grid1Source = New List(Of SomeType)

    For Each a As SomeType In MyFunctions.GetAllCalendarItems(CalendarPicker.SelectedDate)
        grid1Source.Add(a)
    Next
    grid1.ItemsSource = gird1Source

    Dim grid2Source = New List(Of SomeOtherType)

    For Each fa As SomeOtherTypeIn MyFunctions.GetsomeCalendarItems(CalendarPicker.SelectedDate)
        grid2Source.Add(fa)
    Next
    grid2.ItemsSource = grid2Source
```

Now the tricky thing: they are looking different. One of them is containing an empty row. (You can see it in the picture below) And it's not because of bad/empty Objects returned from the function (checked this about 500 times with the debugger).

[image: this is how the DataGrids look like]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: canuseraddrows = false ? the extra row looks like a new row that grid tries to add, if you set  canuseraddrows to false, it should go away

Comment: Yeah it's working! But why I don't need that in second DataGrid? Haven't had the Attribute in both of them.

Comment: that may depend on many factors, starting point would be to check if someOtherType is IEditableObject  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this extra row is a new row that is provided by dataGrid. You need to mark `CanUserAddRows = False` to stop this feature.

this will stop grid from letting user add a new row.

ALso, read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/01/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx) for more info on how CanUserAddRows works

> CanUserAddRows   True if the DataGrid is not ReadOnly and IsEnabled,
>   CanUserAddRows is set to true and IEditableCollectionView.CanAddNew is
>   true